# CSS filter for IE6 standard mode and quirk mode?

Tags: browser, filter, css, internet-explorer-6

Is there any CSS filter can be applied to detect IE6's standard mode and quirk mode?

The story is that a jQuery script is using $.support.boxModel to handle different rendering mode. But the CSS use the *width hack to define the dimension. But this hack can only filter whether the browser is IE but not the real rendering mode IE is on.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in css, but you can include different stylesheets for different versions of IE using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need that? Usually you write a style sheet for one explicit HTML document or at least one specific site where you know whether that page/site is running in quirks or standards mode.

It's not like a page can unexpectedly change modes :-)

If you really need to support a mixture of pages with different modes you'll need to use two separate style sheets, one for each mode.

Comment: It's an unusual case that my app need to live inside different 'container'.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using js injection

```
if(!$.support.boxModel) $('body').addClass('nobox');
```

And then do the styling in CSS.